# How to clone a form with all its sub-grids in Microsoft Dynamics CRM (online)?

Tags: javascript, entity, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

In our CRM Dynamics, 2011; I need to see a ribbon for Cloning on Lead / Account / Contact / Opportunity and all custom entities; that allows my users to clone lead forms with all the data that is already filled in it. For example, if a new form is created and filled with the data when cloning it, part of the data present in the sub-grids are not being copied so we will have to enter them again. I appreciate if  anyone could provide me with a programmatic solution or an add-on that could do the work.

Thanks you!